# How can I detect when a jQuery Mobile popup is shown

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to listen for when a jQuery Mobile popup is shown

I'm using `<a id="linkFoo"  data-rel="popup"  href='#fb-login-page'>` to load `<div data-role="popup"  id="fb-login-popup">`

Using `data-role='page'` when defining a jQuery Mobile internal page, I can listen for 'page show' as follows `$('#pageId').on('pageshow' function() {});`

How can I detect when the popup appears with JQM?

Comment: have you checked the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/events.html) at all?

Comment: I just happened to have the relevant page open :)   http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/events.html  You probably want `popupbeforeposition`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `popupafteropen` equivalent to `pageshow` and `popupafterclose` equivalent to `pagehide`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/QXWDJ/)**

```js
$('#popup').on('popupafteropen', function () {
 // code
}).on('popupafterclose', function () {
 // code
});
```